I have a python script running ok in idle 3.9. The .exe file throws an error No module named 'pyproj._network'. Can anyone help me?
When running the exe file an error occurs: No module Named pyproj._network. The script runs ok in idle 3.9 without any problem. I alread went through many solutions that are posted as reinstalling libraries, installing last version of C++, etc. None has worked.
